# Prove that any group of order 15 is cyclic.

Tags: group-theory

Prove that any group of order $15$ is cyclic.

I know that if order of group is a prime then the group is cyclic, but how to approach such questions?

Comment: Ah, good call. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: This is, indeed, a duplicate, but IMO a better match is [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/67407/11619).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Sylow's theorem we show that there are subgroups $H$ and $K$ of order 5 and 3 respectively (and the are cyclic of course). Due to 15=3*5 there is only one subgroup of order 5 and only one subgroup of order 3 (Sylow's theorem says that $N_{p} \equiv 1 $ mod $p$, where $N_{p}$ is the number of subgroups with order $p$, $p \in \{3, 5\}$, and $N_{p}$ divides $|G|$ so $N_{p} = 1$). Moreover, these subgroups are normal. That is why $G=K*H$ and cyclic.

Comment: how can we prove that subgroups will be normal?

Comment: @SatvikMashkaria, the Sylow theorems tell us that the Sylow $p$-groups for a given $p$ are conjugate to each other.  So what happens if there is only one Sylow $p$-group?

Comment: Sylows subgroup is normal if and only if it is unique ($N_{p} = 1$) (it is Sylow's theorem too).

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I know how to approach this uses Sylow theory.  Here's a very rough outline:

Let $G$ be a group such that $|G| = 15$.

1. Show that the group contains normal subgroups of order $3$ and of order $5$.  Let's call them $H$ and $K$ respectively.
2. Prove the following fact: If $H$ and $K$ are normal, $H \cap K = \{e\}$, and $G = HK = \{hk : h \in H, k \in K\}$, then $G \cong H \times K$.

Hints for #2:

- Prove that $H \cap K$ is a subgroup of both $H$ and $K$.
- Show that $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Once you have done these, you are more-or-less finished.

Comment: what is $H\times{K}$?

Comment: The direct product of $H$ and $K$ (sometimes also known as the direct sum).  The idea with $H \times K$ is to apply this result, since we know $H \cong \mathbb{Z}_3$ and $K \cong \mathbb{Z}_5$: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5969/product-of-two-cyclic-groups-is-cyclic-iff-their-orders-are-co-prime