# If $m$ and $n$ are coprime, $R_{mn}$ is isomorphic to $R_m \times R_n$

Tags: group-theory

I know this is a duplicate, but I don't know ring theory or the Chinese remainder theorem, so I couldn't understand the answers of the duplicate.

I tried to prove it by constructing the isomorphism $\phi: x \mapsto (x \mod m, \ x \mod n)$. I already proved that this maps $U_{mn}$ to $U_m \times U_n$ and that it is injective, but I'm stuck on proving that it is surjective, or that $|U_{mn}| = |U_m \times U_n|$.

Comment: What is $R_m$? Do you mean $\mathbb Z_m$?

Comment: @rschwieb no, $R_m$ is the set of all integers between 1 and m that are coprime with $m$ under multiplication modulo m

Comment: In that case, a more standard notation would be $U_m$ or $(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)^\times$

Comment: I suppose [this is the duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1659806/29335) you're alluding to. Let's make a note here that you're specifically saying you're stuck on surjectivity, so that people notice it's not a duplicate.

Comment: An alternative indirect way to do it would be to prove $\mathbb Z_{mn}\cong \mathbb Z_m\times \mathbb Z_n$ are isomorphic rings (when $m$ and $n$ are coprime), and then automatically their groups of units are isomorphic.

Comment: This was asked a long time ago, but I hope this helps as it is the simplest way:

You know that:

$|U(m)\times U(n)| = |\phi(m)\times\phi(n)| = |\phi(mn)| = |U(mn)|$

Note that $\phi$ is the totient function here and not the name of your function.
The above equation means ***order of the domain = order of co-domain***

You've proven that the mapping is injective, which means ***order of domain = order of the range***.

So you know ***order of range = order of co-domain***, which is the definition of surjectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for surjectivity: Remember (or look up) Bezout's lemma.

Comment: I don't see how we can apply it to anything else than $m$ and $n$, so there exist integers $x, y$ such that $mx + ny = 1$. Then we want to write an element $(a, b) \in R_m \times R_n$ as $(z \mod m, z \mod n)$. Multiplying both sides of Bezout's lemma by $a$ gives $amx + any = a$. Either $x$ or $y$ is greater than 0, assume it's $x$. Then $amx \mod n = a$. So $n | (amx - a)$. I don't see how to proceed. Can I get another hint?

Comment: When you have $mx+ny=1$ and you're given $(a,b) \in R_m \times R_n$, consider the integer $bmx+any$.

Comment: So something like this?: let $z = bmx + any$. Then $z \mod m = any \mod m$. But $any - a = a(ny - 1) = a(mx)$, so $m | any - a$, so $a = any \mod m = z \mod m$. In the same manner $b = z \mod n$. Suppose $z$ is not coprime with $mn$, then it has a factor $d$ that either divides $m$ or $n$ but not both since $m, n$ are coprime. Assume $d | m$ without loss of generality. Then $d | any$, so it divides $ay$. I still don't get how this integer is coprime with $mn$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to prove this directly, but you can use the fact that $\gcd(z,m)=1$ and $\gcd(z,n)=1$ [implies that $\gcd(z,mn)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/673119/348926). Do you see why $z$ is coprime to $n$ and $m$?