# Proving that a Group isn't Cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I'm trying to prove that the group below isn't cyclic:

$G = \{ (1, 2, 3, ... n)^a\cdot(n+1, n+2, n+3, ... 2n)^b \mid 0 \leq a,b \leq n-1 \}$

To do this, I'm trying to show that none of the elements of $G$ have order $n^2$ - however I've made little progress.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Jack

Comment: What does the notation $G = \{ (1, 2, 3, ... n)^a\cdot(n+1, n+2, n+3, ... 2n)^b \mid 0 \leq a,b \leq n-1 \}$ mean?

Comment: Sorry maybe I should have been more specific. $(1, 2, 3, ... n)$ and $(n+1, n+2, n+3... 2n)$ represent permutations (in k-cycle notation) - and I'm examining the group formed by taking products of powers of these cycles.

Comment: @Jack no power of (1,2,...n) belongs to the subgroup generated by (n+1,...,2n)

Answer (score 4):

Let $\alpha = (1,2,3,\dots,n)$ and $\beta = (n + 1, n + 2, \dots, 2n)$. Then given any element $\alpha^a\beta^b$, $(\alpha^a\beta^b)^n = \alpha^{na}\beta^{nb} = e$ since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ commute. You might also like to show that $G \cong Z_n \times Z_n$ where $Z_n$ is the cyclic group of order $n$ and the isomorphism is $\alpha^a\beta^b \mapsto (a,b)$. Then you would need to show that $Z_n \times Z_n \not\cong Z_{n^2}$.

Comment: Thanks T.Gunn. Can I use the first two sentences of your answer to deduce that the maximum order of an element of $G$ is n and hence none of them have order $n^2$?

Comment: @Jack That is correct, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, if $g \in G$, then $g^n=1$. So the order of every element in $G$ is at most $n$.

Comment: I'm not sure whether that's correct - for instance the identity is an element of the group but it's order is 1 - not n?

Comment: I said, *at most $n$*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ihf - and sorry for not catching on - but can you explain why $g^n$ must equal 1 and, why that means the order of every element in G is at most $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The group is generated by two cycles $\sigma = (1, \dots, n), \tau = (n+1, \dots, 2n)$ in $S_{2n}$.  These cycles are disjoint obviously.

Define $\Bbb{Z}_n \times \Bbb{Z}_n \xrightarrow{\phi} S_n$ by $a \times b \mapsto \sigma^a \tau^b$.  Then this is an embedding as $\phi(a,b) = \text{id} \implies a = b = 0$ or else $\sigma^a \tau^b = \text{id}$ so that $\tau$ is not only not a disjoint cycle from $\sigma$ it is an iterate of it ($\sigma^k$, for some $k$).

But according to this lemma:
[The direct product of two cyclic groups is cyclic iff their orders are coprime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5969/product-of-two-cyclic-groups-is-cyclic-iff-their-orders-are-co-prime).

It's nice to use other results.  It reduces the workload of what you're trying to prove.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, unfortunately, I haven't seen much of the notation which you've used before. I have neither encountered "direct products" of groups. I don't suppose there is a simpler answer akin to Ihf's?

Comment: @Jack what's an lhf?